# Why "M < 10 is basically push or fold"?

Tags: poker-theory, no-limit, pre-flop

I'm learning [MIT's Poker Theory and Analytics](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-s50-poker-theory-and-analytics-january-iap-2015/pages/lecture-notes/) class. I don't understand the following argument in pre-flop analysis:

> M < 10 is basically push or fold
> – Why not raise? A bet of 3BB (i.e. 2 M) lets you fold to a re-raise if it’s as much as
> 6M (i.e. giving you pot odds of 8 / 20 or 40%). You can fold 99- A5- K9- on a very small margin. Less than 4M remaining gives you pot odds of 4 / 12 or 30% which is basically always a call. So maximizing fold equity is most important.

So here M stands for [M-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ratio). I don't understand how exactly the pot odds in two scenarios are calculated. Could someone tell me the complete hand history the lecturer was referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, part of the advantage of raising all in, is being able to win un-contested. and the smaller a raise, the less likely one is too win uncontested. at 10 M's and below, you simply doo not have enough chips to be a threat and, and you should push, instead of making weak calls hoping to flop a hand, time to fix bayonets and make that noble last stand to turn the war.
personally if I am short I am looking for a hand, a big part of the decision is if I am first in or not. the earlier the better, want people making a decision on making a cold call.